# Why does the Rails executor not recognize refinements on Kernel?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, refinements

**update that's burried in an answer comment below:** the problem was happening in ruby 2.7, this is fixed in ruby 3

---

I discovered that if code is run within a [Rails executor](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/threading_and_code_execution.html#executor), refinements are not recognized. It doesn't seem to be because of blocks or procs, which was my only guess. Here's some demo code:

```rb
require './config/environment.rb'

module ExammpleRefinement
  refine ::Kernel do
    def say_hello
      puts "hello"
    end
  end
end

using ExammpleRefinement

puts "alone"
say_hello
puts "block"
loop do
  say_hello
  break
end
puts "proc"
Proc.new{say_hello}.call

puts "rails executor"

::Rails.application.executor.wrap do
  say_hello
end
```

run with `ruby example.rb` (can't do it with `rails runner`, because starting in rails 7 it wraps the entire script in an executor, so it ruins the experiment)

```
alone
hello
block
hello
proc
hello
rails executor
Traceback (most recent call last):
    2: from example.rb:25:in `<main>'
    1: from ....rbenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.4/lib/active_support/execution_wrapper.rb:92:in `wrap'
scripts/example.rb:26:in `block in <main>': undefined local variable or method `say_hello' for main:Object (NameError)
```

ruby 2.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wasn't able to reproduce the behaviour with the exact test file you provided (in my test it failed immediately after requiring `config/environment`, regardless of executor wrapping), but I imagine I've tracked it to the same cause anyway:

During application initialization, likely due to use of EventedFileUpdateChecker, [Kernel gets prepended by ForkTracker](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/cf2be235771e562393727510ec58e060c18cadd2/activesupport/lib/active_support/fork_tracker.rb#L53).

Presumably (and somewhat understandably), refinements doesn't like that.

Comment: In my environment I had eager_load off, if I turn it on I get the behavior you get.

Comment: Looks like that was it! If I `refine ActiveSupport::ForkTracker::CoreExtPrivate` instead, my script works. Now to consider if this is reliable, if I need to detect rails versions, etc.

Comment: I believe it's fixed in ruby 3, probably because of this https://rubyreferences.github.io/rubychanges/3.0.html#include-and-prepend-now-affects-modules-including-the-receiver